# An unrecognized external harddrive on some PC

Tags: windows, windows-vista, external-hard-drive

I have a Western Digital Password external HD USB2.0

I works on some computer (a desktop PC with Vista, a laptop with XP)
and do not works on some other.

I makes an iterative "tick" noise and sometime even makes a beep sound!
(it is not even shown on the Windows the device manager)

(I tested it with Hiren Boot CD also : it is the same issue...)

What can I do to make it regonized on all computers?
Does it come from the PC usb controller ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the drive is dying.  I would connect it to a computer that recognizes it and back up all the data, then see if you have a warranty on it.  Most of these come with a one-year manufacturers warranty.  The "tick" noise is a sign that the drive is malfunctioning.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative ticks are very bad signs on hard drives. It could be a lack of power on the USB bus to power it, but is also likely to be the sign of a dying hard drive.